# Getting Return Value from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to get the return value from a stored procedure in C# but it is always returning {}. My code looks as follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ( );
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.verifyEmailDomain @Domain, @RESULT";
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlParameter domain_p = new SqlParameter ( "@Domain", SqlDbType.NVarChar );
domain_p.Value = domain;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( domain_p );

SqlParameter ret = new SqlParameter("@RESULT", SqlDbType.Int);
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( ret );

con.Open ( );
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ( );
var value = cmd.Parameters ["@RESULT"].Value;
con.Close ( );
```

I have also attempted to set "ret.Direction = ParamaterDirection.ReturnValue" to no avail

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[verifyEmailDomain]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Domain nvarchar(200),
    @RESULT INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @RESULT = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Josh.dbo.refDomains 
    WHERE LOWER(EMAIL_DOMAIN)=LOWER(@Domain)

    RETURN @RESULT
END
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a stored procedure with an output parameter you need to tell it so:

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.verifyEmailDomain @Domain, @RESULT OUTPUT";
```

You can save yourself the bother by just specifying the procedure name:

```
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.verifyEmailDomain";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: That did it! Is there a cleaner way to implement this?

Comment: @joshua-philpott The second option is generally the way to call stored procs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating another variable called return, why don't you just return the select statement?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[verifyEmailDomain]
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @Domain nvarchar(200),
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    RETURN(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Josh.dbo.refDomains 
    WHERE LOWER(EMAIL_DOMAIN)=LOWER(@Domain))
END
```

Then change this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ( );
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.verifyEmailDomain @Domain, @RESULT";
cmd.Connection = con;
```

To look like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ( );
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.verifyEmailDomain";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;
```

And this:

```
SqlParameter ret = new SqlParameter("@RESULT", SqlDbType.Int);
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( ret );
```

To look like this:

```
SqlParameter ret = new SqlParameter();
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
ret.ParameterName = "@RESULT";
cmd.Parameters.Add(ret);
```

At this point in time, your sql returns the value of @Return and the return value which are both the same thing. Kind of pointless I think :).

Comment: I think that is definitely the way to do it. That is originally what I did but I changed the stored procedure in an attempt to get it working. I think the essence of the question for anyone who finds this later is to be sure to set the CommandType to StoredProcedure and set the parameter direction to ParameterDirection.Output or ParameterDirection.ReturnValue (depending upon the stored proc implementation)